# Creating a unique id (PIN) for each record of a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a PIN that is unique within a table but not incremental to make it harder for people to guess.
Ideally I'd like to be able to create this within SQL Server but I can do it via ASP.Net if needed.

**EDIT**

Sorry if I wasn't clear: I'm not looking for a GUID as all I need is a unique id for that table; I just don't want it to be incremental.

Comment: How many digits?  Numeric or Alpha Numeric?  Of course there are all of the issues with securely communicating the initial PIN.

Comment: <pedant>A personal identification number...number?</pedant>

Comment: ideally as short as possible - can be ether numeric or alpha numeric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a [uniqueidentifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx) column to your table, with a default value of NEWID(). This will ensure that each column gets a new unique identifier, which is not incremental.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
   ...
   PIN uniqueidentifier NOT NULL DEFAULT newid()
   ...
)
```

The uniqueidentifier is guaranteed to be unique, not just for this table, but for all tables.

If it's too large for your application, you can derive a smaller PIN from this number, you can do this like:

```
   SELECT RIGHT(REPLACE((SELECT PIN from MyTable WHERE UserID=...), '-', ''), 4/*PinLength*/)
```

Note that the returned smaller PIN is not guaranteed to be unique for all users, but may be more manageable, depending upon your application.

EDIT: If you want a small PIN, with guaranteed uniqueness, the tricky part is that you need to know at least the maximum number of users, in order to choose the appropriate size of the pin. As the number of users increases, the chances of a PIN collision increases. This is similar to the [Coupon Collector's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) problem, and approaches n log n complexity, which will cause very slow inserts (insert time proportional to the number of existing elements, so inserting M items then becomes O(N^2)). The simplest way to avoid this is to use a large unique ID, and select only a portion of that for your PIN, assuming that you can forgo uniqueness of PIN values.

EDIT2:

If you have a table definition like this

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable (
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [pin]  AS (CONVERT(varchar(9),id,0)+RIGHT(pinseed,3)) PERSISTED,
    [pinseed] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
)
```

This will create the `pin` from the `pinseed` a unique ID and the row id. (RAND does not work - since SQL server will use the same value to initialize multiple rows, this is not the case with NEWID())

Just so that it is said, I advise that you do not consider this in any way secure. You should consider it always possible that another user could guess someone else's PIN, unless you somehow limit the number of allowed guesses (e.g. stop accepting requests after 3 attempts, similar to a bank witholding your card after 3 incorrect PIN entries.)

Comment: maybe i can use the start like you suggest and join it to the id of the row to create a unique id - would that work?

Comment: Yes, that would work if you append say 3 additional digits to the end of the row id. Rather than the uniqueidentifier, I'd probably append a simple random number to the row id, which may be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a GUID

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier

Most languages have some sort of API for generating this... a google search will help ;)

Comment: OMG, you're going to assign me a GUID as my PIN and make me type in all that gibberish? I'll have to write the darn thing down, as there's no way to remember that long of a string.

Comment: the point is that i don't need a guid as it is too long and i only need it to be unique to that table.

Answer (score 0):

How about a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER type column with a default value of NEWID()?

That will generate a new GUID for each row.

Comment: again i don't need a GUID - see comment on @smdrager

Answer (score 0):

Please have in mind that by requiring an unique PIN (which is uncommon) you will be limiting the max number of allowed users to the the PIN specification. Are you sure you want this ?

A not very elegant solution but which works is to use an UNIQUE field, and then loop attempting to insert a random generated PIN until the insert is successful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to generate a BIGINT, or other datatype.

```
SELECT CAST(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%2000000000+1 as BIGINT) as [PIN]
```

This creates a number between 1 and 2 billion.  You will simulate some level of randomness since it's derived from the NEWID function.  You can also format the result as you wish.

This doesn't guarantee uniqueness.  I suggest that you use a unique constraint on the PIN column.  And, your code that creates the new PIN should check that the new value is unique before it assigns the value.

Answer (score 0):

Use a random number.

SET @uid = ROUND(RAND() * 100000)

The more sparse your values are in the table, the better this works.  If the number of assigned values gets large is relationship to the number of available values, it does not work as well.

Once the number is generated you have a couple of options.
1) INSERT the value inside of a retry loop.  If you get a dupe error, regenerate the value (or try the value +/-1) and try again.
2) Generate the value and look for the MAX and MIN existing unique identifiers.

```
DECLARE
    @uid    INTEGER
SET @uid = ROUND(RAND() * 10000, 1)
SELECT @uid
SELECT MAX(uid) FROM table1 WHERE uid < @uid
SELECT MIN(uid) FROM table1 WHERE uid > @uid
```

The MIN and MAX value give you a range of available values to work from if the random value is already assigned.

Comment: OP wanted " PIN that is unique within a table" ... your implementation may feel correct at first, but the chances of a collision approach 50% with less than 2500 rows.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem for more information.